# Display time automatically updating every minute

Tags: qt, qml

I have an QML application in which I'm trying crate a simple clock that would show current time - similar as those in every operating system.

The time is supposed to be presented to the user as a text in format `hh:mm`, so *i.e.* 16:12.

Currently I'm trying a solution with a [Timer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-timer.html) component running during the application lifetime and updating the text by invoking:

`timeText.text = Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"hh:mm")`

every 60 seconds. Is there a better way to do this or using a [Timer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-timer.html) component is necessary.

Snippet with the whole code:

```
Text {
    id: timeText
    x: 10
    y: 10
    text: Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"hh:mm")
}

Timer {
    id: timer
    interval: 60000
    repeat: true
    running: true

    onTriggered:
    {
        timeText.text =  Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"hh:mm")
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is a simple way, there's nothing wrong with it. That's what the timer component is for. Alternatively, you can create a model in either QML or C++ that updates its value every minute. In C++, the model can be a `QObject` property, so it can be very short.

Comment: The only thing I would change it to avoid doing the `Timer` every minute because, especially on Windows, the `Timer` are not precise enough. You should do one that fires every second and update the date accordingly. Otherwise you end up risking firing 1 second too early sometimes and just keeping the same minute displayed twice

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is a few years old now, but no solution was given, so here's how I did it (this applies to SailfishOS);

Add a property;

```
    property alias updatesEnabled: timeText.updatesEnabled
```

Then, the important part;

```
    Item {
    id: timeText
    color: timeText.color
    font.pixelSize: Theme.fontSizeHuge * 2.0
    text: { updatesEnabled: timeText.time  <--------add line here
        Qt.formatTime(new Date(), "hh:mm:ss")
    }
    anchors {
        horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
}
```

The above now keeps the time/date up-to-date. I played around inserting the code at different lines, but this was the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

.qml

```
        Item{
            Timer{
              interval:60000; running:true; repeat: true
              onTriggered: time.text=Tcp.time()
            }

        Text{
            id:time
            color: "white"
            font.pointSize: 20
        }}
```

.cpp

```
QString Tcp::time()
{
           return QDateTime:currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).